# Rails 3 + angularjs + minification does not work in production: Unknown provider: eProvider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, assets, production, minify

I've followed all the instructions I can find for fixing minification, e.g.

```
var MyController = function(renamed$scope, renamedGreeter) {
...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
```

and

```
someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) {
...;
}]);
```

yet angular refuses to work still.  It always throws the error "Unknown provider: eProvider"

Here are my two attempts to get it working... can anyone help?

https://github.com/jemminger/angular-test1

https://github.com/jemminger/angular-test2

They've already had the assets precompiled and development mode is configured to work as production, so you should just be able to "rails s" to see it (not) work.

Comment: Depending on one's goals, a possible solution is to scale back the minifier to less-desctructive optimizations. In the case of `uglify` you can use the `mangle: false` configuration and still save quite a few kilobytes with whitespace removal.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Found it!  They never said to apply the injection fixes to services too... The solution is to change this:

```
angular.module('itemServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Item', function($resource){
      return $resource('items/:item_id.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{ item_id: 'all' }, isArray:true}
      });
    });
```

to this:

```
angular.module('itemServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Item', ['$resource', function($resource){
      return $resource('items/:item_id.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{ item_id: 'all' }, isArray:true}
      });
    }]);
```

Comment: @Josiah, it works because the dependency injection allows the function to survive js minification.

Comment: I suggest using ng-strict-di (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) to detect the issue also in development env

Answer (score 14):

Remember, to also use DI on controllers within directives. Took me hours... CS example:

wrong:

```
controller: ($scope) ->
  $scope.closeModal = ->
    ModalService.close()
```

right:

```
controller: ["$scope"
  ($scope) ->
    $scope.closeModal = ->
      ModalService.close()
]
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if it didn't rely on the reader using your choice of scripting solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to apply the DI pattern to *ALL* function definitions that require injection within your module. It can be easy to miss one. If you're using a routeProvider, factory, services, etc., they all need to have the DI pattern applied. I ended up deploying multiple times before I caught them all :P

Comment: 'It can be easy to miss one.' Exactly. You must apply the pattern even to the controllers defined in directives! I wasted one wonderful hour searching for this bug.